# Controlling USB media access on Red Hat or Centos Linux 6.3

Tags: usb-storage, centos-6, redhat-enterprise-linux

I'm trying to control which users can use USB media (mass storage devices such as USB memory sticks and hard-drives) on Red Hat/ Centos 6.3 Linux. I would like something that is network wide, so a group permission based scheme would be preferred, e.g. where a user is put in a group and that gives them read-only or read-write access, etc.

I have been told that mediad can be used to manage this but I can't figure out how. I've also come across cgroup/ cgconfig but cannot figure out how to configure the blkio to achieve what I'm after.

How should I go about achieving this?